# Running 7.0SDK build on iOS9 beta

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9

I have an app(iPad/iphone) in App Store that is compatible with SDK 7.0 and 8.0 compatible. What are possible problems that users may face when they will upgrade their devices to iOS 9. Has any body come across any such issues ?

Comment: Just upgrade your phone to iOS9 and test it, thats probably the easiest way to find yout

Comment: I am doing that, but other than some UI minor differences I am not able to find any major problems. Is this expected ?. I wanted to know some common problems people might have faced so that I can check specifically for those.